# WSO2 ESB payload factory XML Exception

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Lately any attempt to call API resources on my ESB has resulted in an XML exception (stack trace below) when run by the payloadFactory. Removing the payloadFactory in its entirety seems to be the only way to resolve this. I can have no args, empty format, or completely static args and format in ways that should work, and did work yesterday!

The build is on ESB 5.0.0 and an example of such a resource looks like this:

```
<resource methods="POST" uri-template="/someUrl">
    <inSequence>
        <property name="acceptedRoles" value="RMD" scope="default" type="STRING/>
        <property name="myProp" value="json-eval($)" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
        <Package.ConnectorOne/>
        <Package.ConnectorTwo/>
        <loopback/>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence>
        <payloadFactory media-type="json">
            <format>{"statusCode":$1,"errorMessage":"$2","errors":$3}</format>
            <args>
                <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('statusCode')/>
                <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('errorMessage')/>
                <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('errors')/>
            </args>
        <payloadFactory>
        <send/>
    </outSequence>
    <faultSequence/>
</resource>
```

Exception stack traces:

```
TID[-1234] [ESB] [2017-03-21 19:22:33,024] ERROR
{API_LOGGER.FleetManagement} - javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException:
Unexpected symbol: START_OBJECT
org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.buildNext(OMElementImpl.java:653
)
org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSourcedElementImpl.buildNext(OMSourcedElemen
tImpl.java:880)
org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMNodeImpl.getNextOMSibling(OMNodeImpl.java:12
2)
org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.getNextOMSibling(OMElementImpl.j
ava:343)
org.apache.axiom.om.impl.traverse.OMChildrenIterator.getNextNode(OMChildrenI
terator.java:36)
org.apache.axiom.om.impl.traverse.OMAbstractIterator.hasNext(OMAbstractItera
tor.java:58)
org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.removeIndentations(JsonUtil.java:41
8)
org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.removeIndentations(JsonUtil.java:42
5)
org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.getNewJsonPayload(JsonUtil.java:587
)
org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.getNewJsonPayload(JsonUtil.java:654
)
org.apache.synapse.mediators.transform.PayloadFactoryMediator.mediate(Payloa
dFactoryMediator.java:173)
org.apache.synapse.mediators.transform.PayloadFactoryMediator.mediate(Payloa
dFactoryMediator.java:104)
org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediat
or.java:97)
org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediat
or.java:59)
org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.
java:158) org.apache.synapse.rest.Resource.process(Resource.java:343)
org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:338)
org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.apiProcess(RESTRequestHandler.jav
a:123)
org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.
java:101)
org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:5
6)
org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2Syn
apseEnvironment.java:304)
org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LoopBackMediator.mediate(LoopBackMediat
or.java:63)
org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediat
or.java:97)
org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediat
or.java:59)
org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.
java:158) org.apache.synapse.rest.Resource.process(Resource.java:343)
org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:399)
org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.apiProcess(RESTRequestHandler.jav
a:123)
org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.
java:101)
org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:6
9)
org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2Syn
apseEnvironment.java:304)
org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageR
eceiver.java:75)
org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosing
RESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:325)
org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingReq
uest(ServerWorker.java:371)
org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:151
)
org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerP
ool.java:172) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown
Source) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

And

```
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Unexpected symbol: START_OBJECT
org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.buildNext(OMElementImpl.java:653
)
org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSourcedElementImpl.buildNext(OMSourcedElemen
tImpl.java:880)
org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMNodeImpl.getNextOMSibling(OMNodeImpl.java:12
2)
org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.getNextOMSibling(OMElementImpl.j
ava:343)
org.apache.axiom.om.impl.traverse.OMChildrenIterator.getNextNode(OMChildrenI
terator.java:36)
org.apache.axiom.om.impl.traverse.OMAbstractIterator.hasNext(OMAbstractItera
tor.java:58)
org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.removeIndentations(JsonUtil.java:41
8)
org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.removeIndentations(JsonUtil.java:42
5)
org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.getNewJsonPayload(JsonUtil.java:587
)
org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.getNewJsonPayload(JsonUtil.java:654
)
org.apache.synapse.mediators.transform.PayloadFactoryMediator.mediate(Payloa
dFactoryMediator.java:173)
org.apache.synapse.mediators.transform.PayloadFactoryMediator.mediate(Payloa
dFactoryMediator.java:104)
org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediat
or.java:97)
org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediat
or.java:59)
org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.
java:158) org.apache.synapse.rest.Resource.process(Resource.java:343)
org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:338)
org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.apiProcess(RESTRequestHandler.jav
a:123)
org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.
java:101)
org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:5
6)
org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2Syn
apseEnvironment.java:304)
org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LoopBackMediator.mediate(LoopBackMediat
or.java:63)
org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediat
or.java:97)
org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediat
or.java:59)
org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.
java:158) org.apache.synapse.rest.Resource.process(Resource.java:343)
org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:399)
org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.apiProcess(RESTRequestHandler.jav
a:123)
org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.
java:101)
org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:6
9)
org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2Syn
apseEnvironment.java:304)
org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageR
eceiver.java:75)
org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosing
RESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:325)
org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingReq
uest(ServerWorker.java:371)
org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:151
)
org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerP
ool.java:172) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown
Source) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is the expression type in the payload factory mediator while passing the arguments to the json.

```
*<payloadFactory media-type="json">
            <format>{"statusCode":$1,"errorMessage":"$2","errors":$3}</format>
            <args>
                <***arg evaluator="xml"*** expression="get-property('statusCode')/>
                <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('errorMessage')/>
                <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('errors')/>
            </args>
        <payloadFactory>*
```

change the value of ***arg evaluator="xml"*** expression="get-property('statusCode') from xml to ***arg evaluator="json"*** expression="get-property('statusCode')json and give it a try. I believe the exception is due to parsing xml as json.

Comment if the error isn't resolved.
Thanks

Comment: I won't be with my work PC again until tomorrow or Monday, but I have tried this without the arg fields and the result is the same. I will give this a try when I can. Strangely I had a teammate at work try this code on his server and he said it worked fine.

Comment: Yeah, this ended up not solving the issue. Thanks for the idea nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the arguments you are trying to inject into the json payload are not either an `int` or a `boolean` , which would cause a parsing exception.

Try this :

```
 <payloadFactory media-type="json">
            <format>{"statusCode":"$1","errorMessage":"$2","errors": "$3"}</format>
            <args>
                <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('statusCode')/>
                <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('errorMessage')/>
                <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('errors')/>
            </args>
<payloadFactory>
```

To see what is happening in detail during mediation , try setting the synapse logger (`org.apache.synapse`) and wire log to DEBUG.

Comment: I tried upping the debug level as you recommended. I don't see anything in it that will help, but you might see something I don't. Starting what I guess is the beginning of the outSequence

     -<init> on JsonReadOnlyStream

    -#mediate shows my payload as {"asdf":"fdsa"}. I made a constant payload factory for simplicity

-<init> on JsonReadOnlyStream again

    -JsonReaderDelegate sets JsonXmlStreamReader as XMLStreamReader

    -#getLocalName has several entries of "old" and "new" being given values

    -fault sequence starts

Comment: I checked it against a copy from a freshly unpacked ESB I had installed on my home PC just last night and found some superficial changes (tag attributes having switched order, line breaks added) but nothing that should change how they are interpreted by the server. They even both had the same misspelling of "security" around line 712.

Just to make sure I hadn't missed anything I plugged in the newer document and ran it with the same results.

Comment: Could you perhaps paste your updated Proxy with log's included a for the few mediators before the error occurs? I am not sure what your Connectors are doing either ?

Comment: I removed all of the connectors to isolate the issue, and created an API with only one resource which contains only the inSeq, outSeq, and faultSeq. The only mediators within are a loopback in the inSeq and the payloadFactory and send in the out. My dev environment is down for maintenance at the moment but I'll put a full log in a pastebin tonight.

Comment: So the reason I haven't posted a response in a while is that when I logged in on Friday to get a log of what was happening the server worked normally. No idea why. I hadn't changed anything, and as far as I know nothing changed environmentally.